# In Assembly, How to insert data(or code, or symbol) at start of section?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, compiler-construction, elf

I want to insert some data(or code, or symbol) at start of specific section.
Let's assume that insert data `0x11223344` at the start of <.got> section.

```
# gcc -o test test.s
.global main

.section .got.plt
.byte 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44

main:
 nop
```

However, As you can see,
After compile, data is appended at the **end** of <.got.plt> .

```
Disassembly of section .got.plt:

080495dc <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
 80495dc:   f0 94                   lock xchg %eax,%esp
 80495de:   04 08                   add    $0x8,%al
    ...
 80495e8:   86 82 04 08 11 22       xchg   %al,0x22110804(%edx)
 80495ee:   33                      .byte 0x33
 80495ef:   44                      inc    %esp
```

***Question:***

Can I insert data(or code, or symbol) at the **start of section**?
(*..Is there any compile option or something like assembler directive?*)

Comment: The GOT section is automatically generated by the linker, so this one might be difficult to do.  Generally, for stuff like this you need to write a custom linker script.

Answer (score 2):

It's a linking issue, not an assembling one.

If you ask GCC (or better, `ld`) to show the linking script with `-Wl,--verbose` you'll find the line

```
.got.plt        : { *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
```

that instructs the linker to take all the `.got.plt` sections, *in the order of encounter*.

> Normally, the linker will place files and sections matched by wildcards in the order in which they are seen during the link.

<sup>From [here](http://www.scoberlin.de/content/media/http/informatik/gcc_docs/ld_3.html)</sup>

Since you are compiling with the CRT, that implies its own object files, your object files come after it.
I don't know if this ordering is standardised or anything across different versions of GCC, I think it's free to change anytime.

You should be able to confirm that adding `-v` and `-Wl,-M` to the GCC's command line; the first will show you how GCC invokes the linker, for me it's:

```
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../.. /tmp/ccref9XH.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

It's hard to see it, but the `test.s` object file is `/tmp/ccref9XH.o` (assembled a few lines above in the full output) and some CRT object files are passed to `collect2` before it.

The second option will show the mapping between the output and input sections:

```
.got.plt        0x0000000000601000       0x25
 *(.got.plt)
 .got.plt       0x0000000000601000       0x20 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o
                0x0000000000601000                _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
 .got.plt       0x0000000000601020        0x5 /tmp/ccisjx2P.o
                0x0000000000601024                main
```

showing that `crt1.o`'s `.got.plt` section comes first (Note that you left `main` in the `.got.plt` section).

---

I've not found a satisfable way to overcome that.
One possibility is to copy the linker script and change the `.got.plt` definition to something like:

```
.got.plt        : { *(.got.plt.pre) *(.got.plt)  *(.igot.plt) }
```

then you can put your data in the `.got.plt.pre` (NOTE: untested).
But this is a maintainability nightmare.

I've trying playing with `--sort-section=name` of `ld` that add the `SORT` command to each wildcard sections input in the linker script.
This should align sections according to "*file or section name*".
After a few tries I've looked in the source and it is actually section name only, so it's of no use here.

I've reverted to `--sort-section=alignment`.
First, the file `test.s` must be assembled into an object file with `gcc -c test.s -o test.o`.
The problem here is making the `.plt.got` section in `test.o` with a bigger alignment than 8 (the one used by the other `.plt.got` sections).
I've checked `objcopy` but found nothing, maybe someone will find a suitable command?
I've personally patched the `test.o` file with an hex editor, giving that section a 32 bytes alignment.
Then invoking `gcc -Wl,--sort-section=alignment test.o -o test` produces an ELF with the `test.s` section before the others.

However this is a cumbersome solution, though one can easily develop a tool to change an ELF section alignment I'd hope to find an existing one.

I'm sorry that none of the above is a proper answer to your problem.